# iOS Mapbox SDK - How to add MGLPointAnnotation markers into a map layer

Tags: ios, mapbox-ios

I need to find a way to convert markers from `MGLPointAnnotation` to `MGLShapeSource` or similar, in order to add the markers to a map layer and have full control over how to display and cluster them on the map, for example.

I am building an iOS App using `MapBox SDK v5.2`.
The App generates markers internally (title, subtitle, coordinates and icon image name) and the markers are displayed on the map with a callout when tapped. The markers are created using `MGLPointAnnotation()` and added to the map using `mapView.addAnnotation()`.

But in order to have full control on how the markers are displayed, for example clustering them based on zoom level or toggling them ON/OFF, I need to add the markers to a Map layer, using, for example, `MGLShapeSource` and then `style.addSource()` and `style.addLayer()`.

The problem is I cannot find a way to the converter from `MGLPointAnnotation` to `MGLShapeSource` or similar.
I have investigated this but the only solution I can think of is to have the marker information contained in a `GeoJSON` file. But I want to avoid that as the markers are generated within the App when its running, and not from an external read-only GeoJSON file.

Example on how one single poi is created:

```
let poi1 = MGLPointAnnotation()
         poi1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.788534, longitude: -9.494489)
         poi1.title = "poi1"
         poi1.subtitle = "This is the text for poi1"
         poiTitleImage[poi1.title!] = "icon1"

mapView.addAnnotation(poi1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `MGLShapeSource` with an [array of `MGLPointAnnotation`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.3.0/Classes/MGLShapeSource.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLShapeSource(im)initWithIdentifier:shapes:options:) or [`MGLPointFeature`](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.3.0/Classes/MGLShapeSource.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLShapeSource(im)initWithIdentifier:features:options:) objects. From there, you can add a clustered layer similar to this [clustering example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/).

If you would also like to assign text or other data for each point, use `MGLPointFeature` objects, then assign the text as an attributes value.

For example:

```swift
        var features = [MGLPointFeature]()
        for _ in 1...100 {
            let point = MGLPointFeature()

            let lat = Double(arc4random_uniform(180) / 2)
            let lon = Double(arc4random_uniform(360) / 2)

            point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            point.attributes["title"] = "\(lat) \(lon)"
            features.append(point)
        }
        let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredFeatures",
                                    features: features,
                                    options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: 20])
        style.addSource(source)
```

An example of how to present a callout containing the information can be found on the [Mapbox website](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/clustering/). It seems like the `handleMapTap` method may contain what you're looking for.

Essentially, you'll query the map where the user taps. Access the attributes on the selected feature, then display a callout containing that information. The above example uses a `UILabel` to display the information.

If you would like to use a default callout, please see the `handleMapTap` method on the [dynamically style interactive points](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/) example. This example also creates a shape source from JSON data loaded at runtime.

Comment: Yes, we can add points generated in that manner to a layer and I had previously tested on code the clustering example you refer to. The problem I am describing is different: I need to be able to add points to a layer with callout annotations; that means the map displays clustered points represented by various icon images with no text labels; when the user taps on a visible icon (not clustered) a callout appears with a title and subtile.

Comment: Are you asking about how to store the title/subtitle information? If so, I can elaborate on that in my answer.

Comment: Hello, yes and also the information on which image to use - see my code at the start of this post. Thanks.

Comment: please see my response. I have added another example that shows similar behavior to what you want.